# About an integration in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to calculate the following integral with Mathematica

```
Integrate[(E^(2 x (-1 - Sqrt[y])) + E^(
     2 x (-1 + Sqrt[y]))) (-((
      3 E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 - Sqrt[1 + 24 z])))/Sqrt[1 + 24 z]) + (
     3 E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 + Sqrt[1 + 24 z])))/Sqrt[1 + 24 z]) + (E^(
     2 x (-1 - Sqrt[y])) + E^(
     2 x (-1 + Sqrt[y]))) (-((
      E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 - Sqrt[1 + 24 z])) (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 24 z]))/(
      2 Sqrt[1 + 24 z])) + (
     E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 + Sqrt[1 + 24 z])) (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 24 z]))/(
     2 Sqrt[1 + 24 z])), {t, 0, Infinity}, {x, 0, t} , 
 Assumptions -> {Re[Sqrt[1 + 24 z]] < 5 && Re[Sqrt[y]] < 1}]
```

The result we easily obtain is 5/(6 (-1 + y) (-1 + z)), but it takes so much time in Mathematica. 
Do you want to help me improve it more quickly?

Comment: If this is the only integral you want to calculate, you already did it. Why do you want to improve a calculation that you don't need to do again?

Comment: I mean that it is too long to calculate the integral in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your input takes a long time but here is a quick way to solve the integral : leave the integration on `t` indefinite, then do the limits.

```
f[y_, z_, t_, x_] = (E^(2 x (-1 - Sqrt[y])) + E^(2 x (-1 + Sqrt[y]))) (-((3 E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 - Sqrt[1 + 24 z])))/Sqrt[1 + 24 z]) + (3 E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 + Sqrt[1 + 24 z])))/Sqrt[1 + 24 z]) + (E^(2 x (-1 - Sqrt[y])) + E^(2 x (-1 + Sqrt[y]))) (-((E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 - Sqrt[1 + 24 z])) (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 24 z]))/(2 Sqrt[1 + 24 z])) + (E^(1/2 (t - x) (-5 + Sqrt[1 + 24 z])) (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 24 z]))/(2 Sqrt[1 + 24 z])); 

int[y_, z_, t_] = Simplify[Integrate[Integrate[f[y, z, t, x], {x, 0, t}], t]];

(* this is fast *)

Limit[int[y, z, t], t -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> {Re[Sqrt[1 + 24 z]] < 5 && Re[Sqrt[y]] < 1}]

(* 0 *)

Limit[int[y, z, t], t -> 0]

(* -(5/(6 (-1+y) (-1+z))) *)
```

Comment: @minhbsu It takes less than 7 seconds to calculate `int[y,z,t]` on my machine. What do you mean by "slow" ?